# Deleting Rows in Google Sheets that Contain Values from Array or Second Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script that lets me delete rows in a Google spreadsheet that contain specific text values. I am an extremely novice coder at best and tried modifying several similar scripts I found. The only one I can get to work is the following. However, my list of values will be long, potentially hundreds of terms, and the script I have here will be cumbersome to build out for this many values. I am guessing that having the values in an array or second spreadsheet would be much better. It is also case sensitive. I tried lifting code from other scripts to change to all lowercase but I can't get anything to work.

If you would be so kind as to share your collective knowledge, how can I modify this to achieve my goal?

```
    function readRows() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
 var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
 var values = rows.getValues();

 var rowsDeleted = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

 var row = values[i];

   if (row[1].indexOf("test") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 }

 if (row[1].indexOf("TEST") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 }

 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  If you delete rows, it's better to start from the bottom otherwise it messes with your indexing. DelA is the array of strings that you want to base your row removals on.  The indexOf function returns something > -1 if it finds the one of the strings.  Once it finds one it stops on that row after deleting it and moves up one.  The row number is i + 1. I did not assume that you had a header row. If you have a header row then adjust your stop condition to i > 0.

```
function deleteMyRows() 
{
 var delA=['Test','Others'];
 var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var rng = sht.getDataRange();
 var values = rng.getValues();
 for (var i = values.length-1; i > -1; i--) 
 {
   for(var j=0;j<values[i].length;j++)
   {
     for(var k=0;k<delA.length;k++)
     {
       if(values[i][j].indexOf(delA[k])>-1)
       {
         sht.deleteRow(i + 1);
         break;
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

So maybe this is what you really need:

```
 function deleteMyRows() 
{
 var delA=['Test','Others'];
 var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var rng = sht.getDataRange();
 var values = rng.getValues();
 for (var i = values.length-1; i > -1; i--) 
 {
   for(var j=0;j<values[i].length;j++)
   {
     for(var k=0;k<delA.length;k++)
     {
       var lcval=String(values[i][j]).toLowerCase();
       var lcdel=String(delA[k]).toLowerCase();
       if(lcval.indexOf(lcdel)>-1)
       {
         sht.deleteRow(i + 1);
         break;
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps with organizing the terms and makes it much easier to build out my list. I am still looking for a way to enter only lowercase terms in the list but have the script delete all capitalization variations, like I believe is happening in the line of script below. I have tried several times, but I can't get it to work in any of my scripts.

    for (j=0;j<arrayValsToChk.length;j+=1) {
      chkVal = arrayValsToChk[j].toLowerCase() //Change to all lower case;

      if (thisVal.indexOf(chkVal) !== -1) {
        ss.deleteRow(i);